# CSS animation not working at all (online videos code)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am following an online video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjHTKLstbRg) to make a cool looking button I'm near the end of it and it's not doing what it should be doing I have done everything it told me to and even gone through the video 5 times to check everything over please help!
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Button</span>
    <div class="liquid"></div>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
<style>

  @keyframes fade {
    0% {
      transform translate(-50%,-75%) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform translate(-50%,-75%) rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #24252A;
  }

  a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  a span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
  }

  a .liquid {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #4973ff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  a .liquid:before,
  a .liquid:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-75%);
  }

  a .liquid:before {
    border-radius: 45%;
    background: rgba(20,20,20,1);
    -webkit-animation: fade 5s linear infinite;
  }
  a .liquid:after {
    border-radius: 40%;
    background: rgba(20,20,20,1);
    -webkit-animation: fade 10s linear infinite;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You are missing colon after property name.

Change

`transform translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(0deg);`

to

`transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(0deg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of **transform** is `transform: none|transform-functions|initial|inherit;`,  so change it to :

```
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
      transform : translate(-50%,-75%) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform : translate(-50%,-75%) rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```